# Update of a question

Tags: discussion

I asked a question and and I got an answer on the question. Now I have a small related question. Should I make a new question post? If I edit my original question with the new small question, will the question reappear in the 'newest questions' page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is preferred by and large to create a new Question, and give a link to the old Question and Answer for context.

Possibly, if the "small related question" is a simple clarification of the earlier Answer, it would be better to ask this in a Comment on the Answer.

But if the matter is too complicated (requires more setup and explication) to pose in a quick comment, then by all means please post this as a new Question.